# Does the Euler product for the Rankin-Selberg convolution of two eigenforms require the Ramanujan conjecture?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, euler-product

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are weight $k$ eigenforms for the Hecke operators, normalized, with Fourier coefficients $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ respectively. I wanted to see if I could derive a Euler product for
$$L(s,f \times \overline{g}) = \sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{a_{n}\overline{b_{n}}}{n^{s}}$$
without the use of the Satake parameters. By this I mean I do not assume
$$a_{p} = \alpha_{p}+\overline{\alpha_{p}} \quad \text{and} \quad a_{p^{n}} = \frac{\alpha_{p}^{n+1}-\overline{\alpha_{p}}^{n+1}}{\alpha_{p}-\overline{\alpha_{p}}}$$
**My approach so far:** Using the multiplicativity of the coefficients I want to find a closed form expression for the $p$-th part
$$\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{a_{p^{n}}\overline{b_{p^{n}}}}{p^{nw}}.$$
Using the recurrence relation
$$a_{p^{n}} = (a_{p^{n-1}}a_{p}-p^{k-1}a_{p^{n-2}})$$
(and similarily for $\overline{b}_{n}$) I was able to compute:

\begin{align*}
    \sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{a_{p^{n}}\overline{b_{p^{n}}}}{p^{nw}} &= 1+\frac{a_{p}\overline{b_{p}}}{p^{w}}+\sum_{n \ge 2}\frac{(a_{p^{n-1}}a_{p}-p^{k-1}a_{p^{n-2}})(\overline{b_{p^{n-1}}}\overline{b_{p}}-p^{k-1}\overline{b_{p^{n-2}}})}{p^{nw}} \\
    &= 1+\frac{a_{p}\overline{b_{p}}}{p^{w}}+\frac{a_{p}\overline{b_{p}}}{p^{w}}\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{a_{p^{n}}\overline{b_{p^{n}}}}{p^{nw}}+\frac{p^{2(k-1)}}{p^{2w}}\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{a_{p^{n}}\overline{b_{p^{n}}}}{p^{nw}}-p^{k-1}\sum_{n \ge 2}\frac{a_{p^{n-1}}a_{p}\overline{b_{p^{n-2}}}+a_{p^{n-2}}\overline{b_{p^{n-1}}}\overline{b_{p}}}{p^{nw}} \\
    &= 1+\left(\frac{a_{p}\overline{b_{p}}}{p^{w}}+\frac{p^{2(k-1)}}{p^{2w}}\right)\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{a_{p^{n}}\overline{b_{p^{n}}}}{p^{nw}}-\frac{p^{k-1}}{p^{2w}}\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{a_{p^{n-1}}a_{p}\overline{b_{p^{n-2}}}}{p^{nw}}-\frac{p^{k-1}}{p^{2w}}\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{a_{p^{n-2}}\overline{b_{p^{n-1}}}\overline{b_{p}}}{p^{nw}} \\
    &= 1+\left(\frac{a_{p}\overline{b_{p}}}{p^{w}}+\frac{p^{2(k-1)}}{p^{2w}}\right)\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{a_{p^{n}}\overline{b_{p^{n}}}}{p^{nw}}-\frac{p^{k-1}}{p^{2w}}\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{(a_{p^{n}}+p^{k-1}a_{p^{n-2}})\overline{b_{p^{n-2}}}}{p^{nw}} \\
    &-\frac{p^{k-1}}{p^{2w}}\sum_{n \ge 2}\frac{a_{p^{n-2}}(\overline{b_{p^{n}}}+p^{k-1}\overline{b_{p^{n-2}}})}{p^{nw}} \\
    &= 1+\left(\frac{a_{p}\overline{b_{p}}}{p^{w}}+\frac{p^{2(k-1)}}{p^{2w}}-\frac{2p^{3(k-1)}}{p^{4w}}\right)\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{a_{p^{n}}\overline{b_{p^{n}}}}{p^{nw}}-\frac{p^{k-1}}{p^{2w}}\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{a_{p^{n}}\overline{b_{p^{n-2}}}+\overline{b_{p^{n}}}a_{p^{n-2}}}{p^{nw}}.
\end{align*}

But I can't express the last sum in terms of $a_{n}b_{n}$ using the recurrence. If I could do this, the original sum could be isolated and I would be done. Is there something subtle happening or might have I overlooked a detail? I've seen the computation of the Euler product for $L(s,f \otimes \overline{g})$ using the description of the Fourier coefficients using the Ramanujan conjecture so I'm not sure why this isn't working out.

Comment: Hard to guess what you want, how you defined the Rankin Selberg convolution and where you are stuck.
The multiplicativity of the coefficients is due to the multiplicativity of the Hecke operators.
The Ramanujan conjecture is about the absolute value of the coefficients ie. the abscissa of convergence of the Dirichlet series and its Euler products, which has consequences on the abscissa of convergence of the Rankin Selberg convolution as well.

Comment: Ah I probably mean something else then. I made some edits above to explain which assumptions I'm trying to avoide. I hope this helps.

Comment: The recurrence relation is different at the $p$ dividing the level, so perhaps you assume level $1$.

Comment: I do mean level 1.

Comment: It is mildly misguided to try to avoid the Satake parameters (which in this simple situation were known to be serious elements of the situation many decades before Satake's larger work), since they'll arise when we do the elementary linear algebra to parse the Hecke-operator recursion. Don't think of them as fancy constructs, but just names for elementary linear algebra objects (at least in the $GL_2$ case).

Comment: Ah, I did not know that they were known to play a role in the theory before Satake's work. Sounds like I should get more familar with them. Thanks PG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(annoying calculation, no idea why I accepted to do it)

The recurrence relation is different at the $p$ dividing the level, so perhaps you assume level $1$.
If so then

$$L(s,f)=\sum_{n\ge 1} a_nn^{-s}=\prod_p \frac1{1-a_pp^{-s}+p^{k-1-s}}$$ $$=
\prod_p \frac1{(1-\alpha_p p^{-s})(1-\beta_p p^{-s})}
=\prod_p (\frac{\frac{\alpha_p}{\alpha_p-\beta_p}}{1-\alpha_p p^{-s}}-
\frac{\frac{\beta_p}{\alpha_p-\beta_p}}{1-\beta_p p^{-s}})
$$
ie.
$$a_{p^k} = \frac{\alpha_p^{k+1}-\beta_p^{k+1}}{\alpha_p-\beta_p}$$
And simimarly for
$$\overline{b_{p^k}} = \frac{\alpha_p'^{k+1}-\beta_p'^{k+1}}{\alpha_p'-\beta_p'}$$
so that
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n \overline{b_n} n^{-s}=\prod_p \sum_{k\ge 0} 
a_{p^k} \overline{b_{p^k}}p^{-sk}$$

$$=\prod_p\sum_{k\ge 0}
\frac{\alpha_p^{k+1}\alpha_p'^{k+1}+
\beta_p^{k+1}\beta_p'^{k+1}-
\alpha_p^{k+1}\beta_p'^{k+1}-\alpha_p'^{k+1}\beta_p^{k+1}}{(\alpha_p-\beta_p)(\alpha_p'-\beta_p')}p^{-sk}$$

$$ = \prod_p 
\frac1{(\alpha_p-\beta_p)(\alpha_p'-\beta_p')} (\frac{\alpha_p\alpha_p'}{1-\alpha_p \alpha_p' p^{-s}}+\frac{\beta_p\beta_p'}{1-\beta_p \beta_p' p^{-s}}
-\frac{\alpha_p\beta_p'}{1-\alpha_p \beta_p' p^{-s}}
-\frac{\alpha_p'\beta_p}{1-\alpha_p' \beta_p p^{-s}})
$$
$$ = \prod_p \frac{1-\alpha_p\beta_p\alpha_p'\beta_p' p^{-2s}}{(1-\alpha_p\alpha_p'p^{-s})(1-\beta_p\beta_p'p^{-s})(1-\alpha_p\beta_p'p^{-s})(1-\alpha_p'\beta_pp^{-s})}$$
$$ = \prod_p \frac{1-p^{2k-2} p^{-2s}}{1 - p^{-s}a_p\overline{b_p}+ p^{-4s} p^{4(k-1)} - p^{-3s}p^{2(k-1)}a_p\overline{b_p} + p^{-2s}p^{k-1}(a_p^2 + \overline{b_p}^2-2p^{k-1}) }$$
Note that replacing the numerator by $1$ gives the tensor product of automorphic representations $L(s,\pi_f \otimes \overline{\pi_g})$.

Comment: I do think that this is the simplest, and completely honest, computation. It is mildly amazing that it turns out as well as it does: the analogous $\sum_n a_nb_nc_n/n^s$ and higher-degree analogues have natural boundaries, as Kurokawa showed c. 1985, extending Estermann's 1928 results about natural boundaries. Once when I did this in an intro-modular-forms class, a student screamed as it worked out in the end... because it was looking pretty ugly. :)

Comment: Thanks for writing this out!